# Referring to Previous element in middle of column in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a data frame which has a date column and a cumulative sum column. The cumulative sum data ends at a certain point and I want to use a formula to calculate it for the rest of the dates in the date column. What I am having trouble with is having the formula reference the previous cell in the column, starting from where the count reverts to 0 (where the historical cumulative sum ends).

Example below:

```
dates.1 <- c("2016-12-06","2016-12-07","2016-12-08","2016-12-09","2016-12-10","2016-12-11","2016-12-12","2016-12-13","2016-12-14")
count.1 <- c(1,3,8,10,0,0,0,0,0)
drift <- .0456


df.1 <- data.frame(cbind(dates.1,count.1))


for (i in df.1$count.1) {
  if (i == 0) {
head(df.1$count.1, n = 1L)+exp(drift+(qnorm(runif(5,0,1))))
  }
}
```

I cant get the for loop to calculate it right.

The reason n = 5 for the runif is because that is the number of future entries I want to run the formula for.

The desired output would have something along the lines of

```
print(df.1$count.1)

[1] 1 3 8 10 12 13 16 17 18
```

The numbers after the 4th element are just random, the general idea is that the column would be overwritten, keeping the historical data and have the new calculated entries instead of the zeroes.

Any ideas?

Comment: I removed the sentence "I am sure this is not too difficult, but as a novice, I can't quite get it." for 2 reasons. One is that on SO unnecessary comments in questions are discouraged. The other is that when you ask people for help they don't like it if you tell them that the problem you're asking them to solve is easy even though you can't do it yourself. It belittles their efforts and expertise.

Comment: You're right. I'm sorry about that and will keep that in mind in my next post!

Comment: Can you clarify a bit? What are you adding, i.e. why should the next element after 10 be 12, where does the +2 come from, and why is it not +3 for instance? Also, how does `drift` and `runif` fit into this picture?

Comment: Sure, the 12 and the numbers after are purely random, it was just an example of what a possible output could be. 

The whole point of this is that it will eventually be part of a forecasting model which is built on historical trend. That is where the drift part comes from. It is a calculation based on the variance and standard deviation of the historical data. The qnorm(runif(...)) part is just part of the forecasting calculation which should add itself to the previous number

Comment: In this case, when you say *"I cant get the for loop to calculate it right."* - what do you mean? Obviously, your code won't produce the values you have provided, since they are random.

Comment: The loop either kicks back 0's for the answer or an error. I cant produce results that resemble anything similar to what would be expected. If I remove the head(...) part, that equation (the exp(...)) works, and does produce random numbers in a certain range as expected. That points me to the head(...) part of the code as what is not working as I want it to. That part of the calculation is supposed to refer to the previous element in the column and add it with the second part of the calculation, the exp(...) part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to loop. You can get what you want by first identifying the row index at which the `cumsum` stopped:

```
last.ind <- which(df.1$count.1==0)[1]-1
```

Then use this `last.ind` to restart the `cumsum`:

```
set.seed(123)  ## for reproducibility
## simulation of rest of data to cumulatively sum
rest.of.data <- exp(drift+(qnorm(runif(5,0,1))))
df.1$count.1[last.ind:length(df.1$count.1)] <- cumsum(c(df.1$count.1[last.ind],rest.of.data))
print(df.1$count.1)
##[1]  1.00000  3.00000  8.00000 10.00000 10.59757 12.92824 13.75970 17.20085 22.17527
```

If you do want to use a loop, then you should do the following, which gives the same result but will be **slower**:

```
for (i in seq_len(length(df.1$count.1))) {
  if (df.1$count.1[i] == 0) {
    df.1$count.1[i] <- df.1$count.1[i-1] + exp(drift+(qnorm(runif(1,0,1))))
  }
}
```

Notes:

1. Loop over indices of `df1$.count.1` not values.
2. If the value at the current index `i` is `0`, write over that value with the sum of the previous value at `i-1` and the data to be cumulatively summed.

Also, you should not use `cbind` to create your `data.frame`. Doing so in this case will result in `df.1$count.1` being a `factor` instead of `numeric`. The data used is:

**Data:**

```
df.1 <- structure(list(dates.1 = structure(1:9, .Label = c("2016-12-06", 
"2016-12-07", "2016-12-08", "2016-12-09", "2016-12-10", "2016-12-11", 
"2016-12-12", "2016-12-13", "2016-12-14"), class = "factor"), 
    count.1 = c(1, 3, 8, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("dates.1", 
"count.1"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
##     dates.1 count.1
##1 2016-12-06       1
##2 2016-12-07       3
##3 2016-12-08       8
##4 2016-12-09      10
##5 2016-12-10       0
##6 2016-12-11       0
##7 2016-12-12       0
##8 2016-12-13       0
##9 2016-12-14       0
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much for explaining this and for the tip with the cbind!